# Micro-nations and their significance

Tags: international-relations, international-law

Do Micro-nations like the ones proclaimed by individuals(Sealand etc) have any significance or power? Aren't they a threat to the unity of a nation? What actions have been taken against them?

Comment: There are lots of [micro-nations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_micronations) out there, so the post is broad. Can you be more specific?

Comment: The ones proclaimed by a single person like Sealand.

Comment: You should clarify to explain what kind of micro-nations you ask about.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the new information that you posted in your comments.

Answer (score 3):

> Do Micro-nations have any significance or power?

They have significance only if they are situated in strategically important locations, or have valuable natural resources.

For instance,

- Brunei has UK military base
- Bahrain, Kuwait have US military bases
- Mauritius, Seychelles have Indian naval bases

> Aren't they a threat to the unity of a nation?

If you are pointing towards **Maldives**, then the answer is: Yes, if they host a Chinese naval base.

> What actions have been taken against them?

If India has enough economic and military power to compete China, they can try to stop Chinese influence. But, other than that, I don't see anything for India in **Maldives**.

Comment: While not a bad answer, if you read the OPs comments it clarifies that he is not thinking about your examples (which, while being small countries, are internationally recognized) but about individuals of small communities claiming independence within a bigger nation like Sealand. Maybe we do need a `nano-nation` term?

Comment: @SJuan76, he added his comment after I have posted my answer. After 1 hour or so.

Comment: I know, I agree that it is mostly the OPs fault, and I realize that it is annoying when that happens after you have written a good answer. I was notifying you of the change just to ensure that you knew it and to give you the option to adapt your answer if you wanted.